# Test method delete Rspec Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, test, rspec

Estimnados, necesito realizar el test para el metodo 'delete' de mi controlador de 'Plan'. El controlador es el siguiente:

```
def destroy
  @plan.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to admin_plans_url, notice: t('admin.plans.flash.destroy.success') }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Lo que intente realizar en mi test fue algo como lo siguiente, que lo encontre en un posteo de stack:

```
it "deletes plan" do
 plan = FactoryBot.create(:plan)

 expect do
  delete :destroy, params { id: plan.id }
  end.to change(Plan, :count).by(-1)
end
```

Pero me arroja un error de sintaxis como lo siguiente:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/features/integration/plan_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: return load_without_bootsnap(resolved, wrap)

SyntaxError:
 /Users/francofernandez/Documents/app/spec/features/integration/plan_spec.rb:107: 
 syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
 ...  delete :destroy, params { id: plan.id }
 ...                              ^
 /Users/francofernandez/Documents/app/spec/features/integration/plan_spec.rb:107: 
  syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end
  ...destroy, params { id: plan.id }
```

Answer (score 1):

El error está en `params`, es la llave de un *hash*; solo agrega `:` y listo:

```
expect do
  delete :destroy, params: { id: plan.id }
end.to change(Plan, :count).by(-1)
```

Comment: Hice lo que me dijiste pero aun recibo el siguiente error: Failure/Error: delete :destroy, params: { id: plan.id }     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `delete' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Plan:0x00007fc26eaa46e0>

Comment: @francofernandez ¿Especificaste en tu _spec_ que es _controller spec_ (i.e. `type: :controller`)?

Comment: No, como especifico eso y en que parte?

Comment: Al inicio del spec: `Rpec.describe TuClase, type: controller do`

Comment: Tengo definido la siguiente al inicio del spec: RSpec.describe 'holidays', type: 'feature' do

Comment: Entonces te recomiendo utilizar el _path_ en lugar de `:destroy`; por ejemplo, algo similar a `delete plan_path(plan.id)`.